# Props passed through <Link> shows up as undefined

Tags: react-router, react-table

I'm passing down props through react-router  component but when received `state` comes up as `undefined`.

I have made sure the component receiving the props is wrapped in `withRouter`. Just to add I'm using react-table here.

```
{
    Header: "Title",
    id: "title",
    col: "title",
    accessor: ({ id, name }) => {

      console.log(history "history"); // this returns an object as expected

      return (
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: bookShowUrl(id),
            state: {
              prevPath: history.location.pathname
            }
          }}
        >
          {name}
        </Link>
      );
    },
    width: 300
  },
```

How do I fix this so that component rendered on `bookShowUrl(id)` is able to access the `prevPath` props?